# What criteria to use when having with 'unengaged' , ‘straightlined’ or ‘patterned’ responses in questionnaires?

Tags: survey, likert, data-preprocessing

Please consider the following situation, which happens a lot in real life applied research in social sciences.

Some percentage of the respondents give ‘straightlined’ or ‘patterned’ responses to a self-reported questionnaire, consisting of several Likert scales. 
What criteria should be employed to make a decision as to keep or remove these respondents from the database? (I refer here to possible criteria related to percentages, type of patterns, etc.). Also, this is not a situation of missing responses, so no imputation is needed.

It should be noted, in my opinion, that a distinction must be made between scales containing only direct items and scales containing also reversely formulated answers (in the latter case, the decision would be simpler, I presume, since a ‘straightlined’ pattern in answers would indicate clearly either no cognitive processing of the question/item or malicious intent).
I’ve searched for references, but aside for taxonomies and how to identify these responses, I’ve come up empty regarding how to deal with them (except ‘throw them out’).

Comment: A fascinating topic addressed by many books and articles.  No answer short enough to fit here is likely to do it justice.  Suggested search terms:  survey methods, survey error, survey bias, straightlining, psychometrics.

Comment: `they give, constantly, the same rating to all questions, regardless if the questions are reversed or not` Investigate profiles of response patterns (flat pattern, extremes pattern, etc.) - you may do cluster analysis to see if the unusual patterns split clearly off from the bulk of the sample in a form of clear small clusters.

Comment: Thanks @ttnphns, I've read very good answers from you in the past. This doesn't help me much. The question is much simpler. Should you keep this respondents or not, and if so, are you aware of any criteria. Sure, you're write about doing analyses to identify how much their pattern differ from that of the others, but I'm not convinced this is enough to make a decision to eliminate or not.

Comment: Hi, @rolando2! Thanks for answering. Could you provide some specific titles of publications addressing this topic? I've search a lot, but no luck. You say there's plenty of literature out there, which surprises me.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, I think the data should be analyzed as is. To some extent, these patterns are a reflection of the survey as well as a reflection of the population. Basically: crap in, crap out. Long winded questionnaires are guaranteed to fatigue respondents, sensitive or invasive questions will likely induce selective non-response, and younger participants generally do not have the same interest in sharing information, or as much information, as their older counterparts.

Secondly, it is impossible as a statistician to go about "data cleaning" by hand, or even looking at the data to inform a set of rules to anticipate just how badly some people will mis-respond on a survey. When you do this, you are very likely to "cheat" and p-hack so that findings conform to your own preconceived notions of reality.

This is the importance of interpreting the findings with a subjective nature. For instance, diet and physical activity questionnaires are notoriously bad. People lie, exaggerate, and do not respond. I did an analysis which found a positive correlation between reported physical activity and weight: fatter people exaggerated their level of physical activity to such an extent that they exceeded what a healthier person reported. Those results are not surprising when you remember that it is *self-reported* physical activity. I interpreted those findings directly, pointed out that I don't believe them, proposed improvements to the questionnaire, and called it a day.

You can certainly use some statistical methods--or just practical methods--to do a sensitivity analysis. I can't see how advanced algorithmic approaches would be beneficial, principal components analysis would probably reveal all you need to know.

Comment: Hi, @AdamO, thanks! I appreciate how concise and straightforward you answered. You referred to PCA in the end. Could you, please, elaborate a little on that?

Comment: @streamline well by doing dimension reduction with PCA, you can plot responses on an appropriate space (2 dimensional or higher), and observe clusters as well as outlying responses. It is assumed that nonsensical replies would deviate from patterns established by those who reply sensibly, although that is a strong assumption. Using a biplot is often enough to inspect these properties.